# Navigation and motion planning in dynamic uncertain outdoor environment?

Tags: navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I would like to use my robot for navigation and motion planning in dynamic uncertain outdoor environment. So it is not just a indoor , office environment. Which package in ros might be consider (a part of stageros) as usefful for probabilistic autonomous navigation in such complex and large dynamic environment??  Or I should use some probabilistic approaches as module and than implement them in ROS?? Any help will be welcome.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62040/navigation-and-motion-planning-in-dynamic-uncertain-outdoor-environment?/) by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on ROS Answers with karma: 330 on 2013-05-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are definitely going to need more elaborate motion planners. I suggest you take a look at the [SBPL](http://www.ros.org/wiki/sbpl) and [OMPL](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ompl) packages and also the [navigation_experimental](http://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation_experimental) stack. The first two packages are able to implement sampling based planners, which are well suited for navigation in complex, changing environments. You can then find a way to implement different metrics for path evaluation, incorporating probabilistic and dynamic information of the environment. The navigation_experimantal stack has the [eband_local_planner](http://www.ros.org/wiki/eband_local_planner?distro=groovy), which can locally change the robot's path to avoid moving objects.

As far as I know, ROS does not have a ready to use motion planner for dynamic environment. If you want to stick with ROS architecture, my suggestion is that you should think about a **global planner** that is able to plan considering predictions on the motion of moving objects and a **local planner** that is able to escape from unpredicted situations.

---

Originally posted by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) with karma: 4402 on 2013-05-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2013-05-05**:
Many thanks for the help